# Reactive Form - updateOn: blur - Validation with Custom Angular Directive

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

Created a Reactive Form array which has make, model and year as FormGroup and able to display the formcontrols in the html. I am looking for a way to stop the user to enter a duplicate value for the make formcontrol textbox. Validation should be triggered when you focus out of the make formcontrol and should be cleared in case of duplicate found.

The issue here is validation is not triggered when you focus out of the make formcontrol input for the first time. Validation is working fine after making the some changes to the input.

For example :

1. Enter ABC as make for first two controls --> No Duplicate (console message)
2. Clear ABC and enter ABC again --> Has Duplicate (console message)

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-for-stack-overflow-sew2bw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

[Demo] (https://angular-example-for-stack-overflow-sew2bw.stackblitz.io)

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<h3>Reactive Form Test</h3>
<hr />
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Make</td>

      <td>Model</td>

      <td>Year</td>
    </tr>
    <ng-container formArrayName="vehicleInfo">
      <tr
        *ngFor="let obj of vehicleForm.controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
      >
        <td><input formControlName="make" validate-duplicate-make /></td>

        <td><input formControlName="model" /></td>

        <td><input formControlName="year" /></td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</form>

<div *ngIf="myForm.valueChanges | async">
  {{ myForm.value | json }}
  {{ vehicleForm.errors }}
</div>
```

**APP Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      vehicleInfo: this.fb.array([]),
    });

    this.createVehicle();
    this.createVehicle();
    this.createVehicle();

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(this.myForm);
    });
  }

  get vehicleForm() {
    return this.myForm?.get('vehicleInfo') as FormArray;
  }

  createVehicle() {
    const vehicle = this.fb.group({
      make: ['', { updateOn: 'blur' }],
      model: [],
      year: [],
    });
    this.vehicleForm.push(vehicle);
  }
}
```

**Angular Directive**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormArray,
  FormControl,
  NgControl,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  Validator,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validate-duplicate-make]',
  host: {
    '(focus)': 'onFocus($event)',
    '(blur)': 'onBlur($event)',
  },
})
export class ValidateMakeDirective {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, public formControl: NgControl) {}

  onFocus($event: any) {}

  onBlur($event: any) {
    console.log('Blur event called');
    this.formControl.valueChanges
      ?.pipe(
        map((obj) => {
          var controls = <FormArray>this.formControl.control?.parent?.parent;
          var makeControls = controls.controls.map((obj) => obj.get('make'));
          var makeLst = makeControls.filter((res) => res?.value == obj);

          if (makeLst.length > 1) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe((obj) => {
        console.log(obj);
        if (obj == true) {
        
          console.log('Has Duplicate');
        } else {
          console.log('No Duplicate');
        }
      });
  }
}
```

**Custom Validator**

```
export class DuplicateSerTagCheck {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
  static validate(
    controls: FormArray,
    dupsertagerrormsg: DuplicateSerTagErrorMsgService
  ): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if (c.value != null) {
        console.log(c);
        var tmpValues = controls.controls.map((obj) => obj.get('serNo'));
        var finalVals = tmpValues.filter((res) => res?.value == c.value);
        if (finalVals.length > 1) {
          console.log('Duplicate Found');
          dupsertagerrormsg.add(`Found Duplicate - ${finalVals[0]?.value}`);
          c.setValue(null);
          // How to focus
          //this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
        }
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you create a custom validator for this rather than use a directive. It feels like you're trying to stuff a square peg in a round hole...

Comment: Thanks for your input and it worked. I have used custom validator to find the duplicates but I wanted to bring the focus back to the formcontrol (clear the duplicate and focus). I have pasted the modified code in the description. Can you please take a look and advise.